# How to truncate a number in typescript

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make this operation inside an HTML file using Angular with TypeScript: `{{(i / 5) % 3}}`.

The problem is that when `i / 5` does not return a natural number, it can't continue to operate the `% 3` part. So the question is: How can I truncate the `i / 5` in order to get an acceptable result for the operation?

By the way, I tried to use the JavaScript function `Math.trunc(i / 5)` but I get an error that says:

> 'Cannot read property trunc of undefined'

Comment: This question has nothing to do with TypeScript. It has to do with Angular templates. You should fix the title. Anyway, you cannot use `Math` (or any other global) inside a template. In this case, you could use `(~~(i/5)) % 3`. Or calculate it in your TypeScript file.

Comment: Or use `(i - i % 1) % 3`.

Comment: It's better to do the logic in the component and just display the result in the template. i.e., define a method, or a variable to do the math and display the result. This way you have access to Math.* methods too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you want. You could try to use a [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DecimalPipe-pipe.html):

```
{{((i / 5) | number:'1.0-0') % 3}}
```

But looks like the above is rounding.

Answer (score 5):

I could not understand the question. However, you can try 
`Math.floor(i/5) % 3`. This will give erroneous result when you divide by a negative number.

Comment: You cannot use `Math` inside a template.

Answer (score 2):

This question has nothing to do with TypeScript. TypeScript provides no new operators or functions or ways to truncate a number. TypeScript is just a type layer on top of JavaScript.

This is an Angular issue. You cannot use `Math` (any other global variable) in a template. Your options are:

- `(~~(i/5)) % 3`
- `(i/5 - (i/5) % 1) % 3`
- Calculate it in your TypeScript file

Comment: None of these options has worked for me. I got an unexpected token on the first one, the second one gets me the error I have in first place. I'd go with the third, but the main question is how to do it on the template. Thank you for your time and you are right about the `Math` thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three different Math APIs.

Math.floor always gives you lowest number:

```
Math.floor( 1 / 5 ) // 0
Math.floor( 4 / 5 ) // 0
```

Math.ceil always gives you highest number:

```
Math.ceil( 1 / 5 ) // 1
Math.ceil( 4 / 5 ) // 1
```

Math.round gives you the one with most proximity:

```
Math.round( 1 / 5 ) // 0
Math.round( 4 / 5 ) // 1
```

Comment: But you can't use `Math` inside a template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

```
Math.trunc(1.4) // 1
Math.trunc(1.9) // 1
```

Comment: Math.trunc is not supported in typescript

Comment: @DavedeJong Wrong, Math.trunc is part of the ES2015 so it can be used with Typescript. It's perfectly working

Comment: At that time I was working in ES5. Math.trunc is not supported ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote the custom pipe for truncation

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common'

@Pipe({
    name: 'truncateNum'
})
export class TruncateNumberPipe extends DecimalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, digitsInfo?: string): string | null {

        const NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP = /^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/;
        const parts = digitsInfo.match(NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP);

        let maxFraction;

        if (parts === null) {
            throw new Error(`${digitsInfo} is not a valid digit info for number pipes`);
        }

        if (parts[5] != null) {  // max fraction digits
            maxFraction = parseIntAuto(parts[5]);
        }

        return maxFraction ? super.transform(truncateToDecimals(strToNumber(value), maxFraction), digitsInfo) : super.transform(value, digitsInfo);
    }

}

function parseIntAuto(text: string): number {
    const result: number = parseInt(text);
    if (isNaN(result)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid integer literal when parsing ' + text);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
* truncate to decimal place.
*/
function truncateToDecimals(num, dec) {
    const calcDec = Math.pow(10, dec);
    return Math.trunc(num * calcDec) / calcDec;
}
/**
* Transforms a string into a number (if needed).
*/
function strToNumber(value: number | string): number {
    // Convert strings to numbers
    if (typeof value === 'string' && !isNaN(Number(value) - parseFloat(value))) {
        return Number(value);
    }
    if (typeof value !== 'number') {
        throw new Error(`${value} is not a number`);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?